# Change the permission of all the files in a Document Set of a Document Library to Read-Only

Tags: development, event-receivers, sharepoint-on-prem, visual-studio-2013

I've got a document library and I want to change the permission of each file  present in a particular document set (say Office Documents) to **Read-Only** when an item is Updated in a List (say **List A**).
Can anyone please help me achieve this requirement?

P.s  I want to use event receiver to achieve this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the user's permissions on the file then give the user Read-Only permission on the file.

Here is my demo for you:

```
 using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPFolder documentSet = web.GetFolder("http://sp2016/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/DocumentSet");
                SPPrincipal user = web.EnsureUser("contoso2016\\michael");
                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(user);
                SPRoleDefinitionCollection roleDefinitions = web.RoleDefinitions;
                roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinitions["Read"]);
                foreach (SPFile file in documentSet.Files)
                {
                    file.CheckOut();
                    SPItem item = file.Item;

                    item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Remove(user);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                    file.CheckIn("");               
                    item.Update();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use workflows to do this job
or in an eventHandler, remove Delete and edit permissions on this item

```
item.RoleAssignments.Remove(....)
```